# Pre-loading images to set as background-image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pre-load some images and set them as background images.  I'm showing that the images are being loaded, but they're not being brought in as background images but rather, `<img>` elements.  Is it not possible to pre-load background images?

Function to pre-load the images

```
function preloadImage(url){
    var imgObj = new Image();
    imgObj.src = url;
    imgObj.onload = function(){
        console.log(imgObj, "Loaded");
    }
}
```

Object holds the image url's.

```
var Plane_Images = {
    Skin: {
        name: "Skin Schematic",
        src: preloadImage("images/Top.png"),
        schematics: ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    },
    Structure: {
        name: "Structure Schematic",
        src: preloadImage("images/ata21.png"),
        schematics: ["E", "F", "G", "H"]
    },
    Electrics: {
        name: "Electrics Schematic",
        src: preloadImage("images/ata26.png"),
        schematics: ["I", "J", "K", "L"]
    },
    Fuel: {
        name: "Fuel Schematic",
        src: preloadImage("images/Top.png"),
        schematics: ["M", "N", "O", "P"]
    }
}
```

Sets the background image

```
for(var images in Plane_Images){
    var schematic = $("<div data-id='" +id +"_menu' data-url='" +image_src +"'><div class='label'><p>" +images +"</p></div></div>");
    schematic.addClass("schematics");
    schematic.css("background-image", "url(" +image_src +")");

    $("#menu").append(schematic);
}
```

Comment: How does the `for` loop get kicked off? Do you wait for all your `pre-loaded` images before running that script?

Comment: The for loop starts automatically when the document is loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `preloadImage` function never returns a value, so the `src` property is never set.  To ensure that the objects do not get cleaned up after the function is called, I would return the object to a property:

```
function preloadImage(url){
    ...
    return imgObj;
}

var Plane_Images = {
    Skin: {
        name: "Skin Schematic",
        image: preloadImage("images/Top.png"),
        schematics: ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    },
}
```

And access the src by:

```
var image_src = current.image.src;
```

So, two answers: The function should return something. I would return the object, so the pre-loading will not get canceled if the Image Object is cleaned up after the function execution.

Also, your setting function looks a little off:

```
for(var images in Plane_Images){
```

Should probably read:

```
for(var image_name in Plane_images){
    var current = Plabe_images[image_name];
    var image_src = current.image.src;  // Or however you store the source.
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: This doesn't help me as to why it's not being set as the background image though.

Comment: See recent changes to my answer.

Comment: Um, not trying to sound rude or anything, but the for loops are exactly the same, all you did was change the variable name.  Also, when I do `console.log(image_src);` from your example, I'm getting `undefined`

Comment: I actually got it working, I had the return statement in the wrong place.  Sorry for being difficult.

Comment: I just edited the answer so that `image_src = current.image.src` as per the pattern of my other example above it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate way to preload images for use as the background-image property.

```
body:after {
  display: none;
  content: url(img0.png) url(img1.png) url(img2.png);
}
```